# Excel Subtraction Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to input a formula that would calculate a value ONLY if a designated cell is a value NOT zero. For example, the current calculation is Q2=D2-D1. I would like for Q2 to ONLY have a value if D2 has a value NOT Zero. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

You should use the IF function here, whose syntax is:

> IF( this is true; then do this; else, do this )

In your case, the content of cell Q2 should be:

> =IF(D2=0;"";D2-D1)

Comment: If the above formula doesn't work for you, try changing `; semicolon` to `, comma`

Comment: Thanks for the addition. It depends on which language you're using. For English-language spreadsheets, comma works fine. In many non-English languages, however, the decimal place is marked by a comma (e.g. English "0.5" is "0,5"). Naturally, this can cause syntax conflicts which are easily avoided by using semicolon as your default syntax separator.